# KotlinJS Ktor server "Connection closed without response" when deployed to Heroku

Tags: kotlin, heroku, netty, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I'm new to kotlin and having some trouble running my Ktor server on heroku

I'm setting up the server as follows:

```
val port = System.getenv("PORT")?.toInt() ?: 9090
embeddedServer(Netty, port = port) {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText(
                this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("index.html")!!.readText(),
                ContentType.Text.Html
            )
        }
        static("/static") {
            resources("")
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```

When running on my localhost, this responds just fine. And when running in heroku, I get the log output that tells me it did start up the server on the port heroku defines:

```
[main] INFO ktor.application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:55278
```

But then when I try to load the heroku app from the browser, I get an error, and the heroku logs say: `"Connection closed without response"`

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=melomidi.herokuapp.com request_id=e0cdaa83-eaa4-4733-a51f-947de463c433 fwd="174.246.82.169" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

I have tried with both `http` and `https`. I have also tried loading `/static/index.html` directly and got the same result.

I've also tried adding a `SERVER_HOST` env var and using that to change the default `0.0.0.0` host to various things, like `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `melomidi.herokuapp.com` but those resulted in other errors where the server failed to start up.

There are no other details or additional logs being output in the heroku logs when I make the request. Just the one error line per request as displayed above.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After shuffling the order of operations around so that my static resources declaration came first, I started seeing the following error in the logs:

```
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616138+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616138+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.utils.io.jvm.javaio.ReadingKt$toByteReadChannel$1.invokeSuspend(Reading.kt:53)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616138+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.utils.io.jvm.javaio.ReadingKt$toByteReadChannel$1.invoke(Reading.kt)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616139+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.utils.io.jvm.javaio.ReadingKt$toByteReadChannel$1.invoke(Reading.kt)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616139+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.utils.io.CoroutinesKt$launchChannel$job$1.invokeSuspend(Coroutines.kt:132)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616139+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616139+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616139+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616140+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616140+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
2022-01-08T00:19:36.616140+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

That got me to this post:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3358 where I found there is a binary compatibility issue with Ktor server `1.6.5` and `jdk 1.8`

I updated my `jvmTarget` to `11` and now it's up and running!

Strange that I only encountered the issue on heroku though when both my localhost and heroku were each using jdk 1.8 previously.